# Django soft resize uploaded Image to multiple sizes and upload to respective folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, image-processing, django-imagekit

I have the following model on my App

```
def image_path(self, filename):
    return 'app_name/images/{}/{}'.format(slugify(self.name), filename)
        
class Color(models.Model):
    name = CICharField(max_length=22, unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField("Image", upload_to=image_path, blank=True)
```

Once the image is uploaded I want to create 3 images size: small (100 by 100), medium (300 by 300) and large (800 by 800) with the soft image crop. Then I want to manage the URL Structure for my upload.

For Eg.

Original Image URL from "Image" field = 'app_name/images/image_1.jpg'
if I upload the image, Then it will produce the following images.

```
small = 'app_name/images/small/image_1.jpg'
medium = 'app_name/images/medium/image_1.jpg'
large = 'app_name/images/large/image_1.jpg'
```

Can anyone tell me, How can I achieve this on Django.

Thanks.

Comment: you solve that prblem? I have the same implementation...

Answer (score 0):

To do image processing you better use [OpenCV](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/) or [Pillow](https://auth0.com/blog/image-processing-in-python-with-pillow/#:%7E:text=format%20this%20way.-,Resizing%20Images,Image%20with%20the%20new%20dimensions.) or [Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48121916/numpy-resize-rescale-image). Maybe I'm wrong but Django should work ok with OpenCV based scripts.

[Here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html) you have some basic operations with OpenCV.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49170964/how-do-i-save-a-cv2-processed-image-to-django-models) you have how to save processed images in django (similar as you post).

[Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/image-resizing-using-opencv-python/) some resizing pictures code using OpenCV.